# No enclosing instance is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of )

Tags: java, class

I'm new to programming and I'll be studying it next year in uni. In my public static void main ... I can't create a new SimpleCircle. This error occurs only on my circle. Thank you very much for the help! :)

```
public class TestSimpleCircle {

    class SimpleCircle {
        double radius;

        SimpleCircle(){
            radius = 1;
        }

        SimpleCircle(double newRadius){
            radius = newRadius;
        }

        double getArea() {
            return radius * radius * Math.PI;
        }

        double getPerimeter() {
            return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
        }

        void setRadius(double newRadius) {
            radius = newRadius;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SimpleCircle circle = new SimpleCircle();
        System.out.println("the area of the circle of radius "+circle.radius+" is "+circle.getArea());

        SimpleCircle circle2 = new SimpleCircle(25);
        System.out.println("the area of the circle of radius "+circle2.radius+" is "+circle2.getArea());

        SimpleCircle circle3 = new SimpleCircle(125);
        System.out.println("the area of the circle of radius "+circle3.radius+" is "+circle3.getArea());

        circle.radius = 100;
        System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "+circle.radius+" is "+circle.getArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the inner class static.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You declared you SimpleCircle class as inner class for TestSimpleCircle.
You need either move it into a separate file or declare it as

```
static class SimpleCircle
```

Comment: My problem was not reloading the application in tomcat! It needed to reload the class files with the updated inner class as static. Not sufficient to just replace the server files - have to reload application :)

Comment: @Skychan, what your comment has to do with the answer or the question? Wrong window?

Comment: Good point, my comment could be better on the question or as it's own "solution". I don't mind moving it, I guess I just figured I had a different situation than the OP but had exact same error so I wanted to help others who come here for same reason as me, they may see my silly problem/answer because everyone looks at the accepted answer first. I'll move it if you advise.

Answer (score 36):

`SimpleCircle` is an inner class of class `TestSimpleCircle`. This means that you first need an instance of object of enclosing class, for example:

```
TestSimpleCircle tsc = new TestSimpleCircle();
```

Now you are able to create an instance of inner class that is connected with an instance of enclosing `TestSimpleCircle` class:

```
SimpleCircle sc = tsc.new SimpleCircle();
```

As you see, to create an instance of object of inner class you had to specify to which exactly object of enclosing class you want it to belong (with the `tsc.new` in your example).

If you need to create an instance of SimpleCircle without instance of object of enclosing class you should have declared this class as `static class SimpleCircle{code of your class here}`

Comment: ```SimpleCircle sc = tsc.new SimpleCircle();``` is this statement valid ? or you stated it for clarifying only, my 1.8 compiler couldnt understand it.